# Printing Significant Result only on an ANOVA loop in R

Tags: r, loops, plot, anova

I have a data that looks like this:

```
     KAFFE   SAFT    FERSKVARE   HERMETIKK ..... K
      35    23.91     17.3         70.2          1
      53    30.13     27.4         75.7          1
      35    34.54     17.3         81.1          2
      32    31.93     47.3         92.7          2
      34    54.69     17.2         88.4          2 
      35    34.69     19.1         81.5          3 
      54    25.63     18.3         92.1          3 
      34    46.65     18.6         76.6          3
      36    38.21     23.3         79.9          3
```

I used a loop to create an anova and post hoc test for each data

```
rcluso is my data frame
K is the categorical variable located at the end column



sink("AnovaTest.doc")
      for(i in 1:(ncol(rcluso)-1)){
        columns <- names(rcluso[i])
        anovaresult<- summary(aov(rcluso[,i]~K,data=rcluso))
        posthocresult <- TukeyHSD(aov(rcluso[,i]~K,data=rcluso))

    print(columns)
    print(anovaresult)
    print(posthocresult)
    }
    sink()
```

Problem is, I would only like to get the significant result of the anova to be print out and I also want to create a bar plot for each significant result.

Can you guys help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you get the anova() output instead of summary() you can access the p value.

replace your

```
    anovaresult<- summary(aov(rcluso[,i]~K,data=rcluso))
```

with

```
    anovaresult<- anova(aov(rcluso[,i]~K,data=rcluso))
```

then you can conditionally print the results with an if() statement e.g.

```
  if(anovaresult$Pr[1] < 0.05){ print(anovaresult) }
```